# Divide recurring contributions between financial types

Tags: civimember, taxes, donations

I am working on the following scenario. The organization wants to offer anyone that signs up to contribute monthly gets a membership for $100. So if they sign up to donate $50/month the first $100 is the membership dues (non-deductible) and the remaining $500 for that year is considered a donation (deductible).

I have setup the contribution form with a membership type that renews monthly and auto renew is required. That takes care of the payments.

Anyone have an idea on how to record the donations after the initial $100 as a donation that is deductible? It is important to provide the donor a statement at the end of the year for tax purposes.

Any thoughts would be great!

The site is in WordPress 4.9.5 with CiviCRM 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to configure a price set with two line items, one for the membership and one for the donation. You want them to be monthly recurring, so that after 12 months they've paid for the $100 membership: you'll come close with $8.33 /month.

Alternatively, you can create an extension to do this. We'd be happy to help with that.